# Omni-Channel External Routing: Work not being assigned to available Agent

Tags: servicecloud, omnichannel

I'm looking for some advice regarding the setup of **Omni-Channel External Routing**.

While at the project I am currently on we have a `Skills-Based Routing` process in place we'd like to explore the `External Routing` process, and with that in mind created a new sandbox to test this model.

**After following [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.omni_channel_dev.meta/omni_channel_dev/omnichannel_external_routing.htm) and setting up the Queues and External Routing Configurations we're able to see Cases arriving at the Queues Backlog (which also displays available agents).**

[image]

**The main issue is that**: after inserting the AgentWork record related to an Agent that belongs to the Queue in question **nothing changes in the assignment of the Case** (the Agent does not receive any work, the Case is still on the Queues Backlog and nothing changes on the Assigned Work Tab), just a new AgentWork with the default value of Assigned is created.

So far we've tried to turn on auto-acceptance and manually delete the PSR after creating the AgentWork (the first one did nothing and the latter triggered `You can't delete Queue-Based Pending Service Routing records` error while trying to do so).

Would you have a clue of what might be causing this issue and the non-assignment of the work although the agent is online/AgentWork is correctly created?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue where cases were getting assigned to the QUEUE and were visible in queue backlog, but were not getting assigned to the Agents Available.
Solution I Found was that, in the Presence Statuses you need to assign the appropriate service channel to it. So in my scenario I Just needed to add 'Case Channel'(Service Channel) for the 'Available-Chat' Presence Statuses.
[image: Presence Statuses]

Hope it Helps.